# Steam game: Adventureland, flickers to a black screen and is unplayable

Tags: 18.04, steam

I've never used steam before and I'm new to Ubuntu. I'm using 18.04.3 LTS.

I've just downloaded steam and tried to play a game called Adventureland. Everything seems to load fine, but when I try to play the window goes black. Occasionally it flickers on to the game screen, but the buttons don't work and I can't interact with the game.

Comment: Does the game have a native Linux version? If so, complain on the Steam forum rather than here, since it's the game developer's responsibility - especially since both of the games with that name I find on Steam are still Early Access. If not and it's running via Proton, the game may or may not work, there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian - it wasn't intended as a complaint but I suppose I worded it badly. I've found the solution now and posted below.

Comment: "Complain" was maybe a bit harsh - what I meant was "bug report" :) Usually you get more support from game developers in these cases than on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this:
https://adventure.land/linux

It has directions for what to do in the event on black screen.

I ended up opening the game on Steam on a Windows device, activating the game, and then I could simply log in on my browser.